# Pycharm hotkey/setting to change *args call to **kwargs call

Tags: python, pycharm, hotkeys

Let's assume I want to override `__init__` of some class in it's descendant, i.e.

```py
class Parent:
    def __init__(self, arg1, arg2, arg3):
       ...
    ...

class Child(Parent):
    def __init__(self, arg1, arg2, arg3):
        super().__init__(arg1, arg2, arg3)
        ...
```

If I create class child, then press `Ctrl+O` and select to override `__init__` PyCharm will generate something like the above code. But I want to call parent with `**kwargs` init instead of `*args`:

```py
# instead of this
# super().__init__(arg1, arg2, arg3)
# I want this (by settings/hotkey)
super().__init__(arg1=arg1, arg2=arg2, arg3=arg3)
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you want *all* callers to always need to use keyword arguments? Because you could put a `*` in the base class `__init__` method, between `self` and the other args, and it would make them keyword-only. I'm not certain PyCharm's override code generation will handle that, but there's a decent chance it will.